# How to “formally” get rid of $\pm$ from the solution of this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While solving the differential equation for simple harmonic motion, $m\ddot x=-kx$, one gets the following differential equation:

$$\dot x=\pm \, \omega \sqrt{A^2-x^2},$$

where $\sqrt{k/m} \equiv \omega$ and $\sqrt{2E/k} \equiv A$. ($E$ is the conserved (*i.e.* constant) energy.)

$\pm$ sign makes sense cuz the object can have two oppositely signed velocities at the same position.

Now using separation of variables,

$$\int {\text{d} x \over \sqrt{A^2-x^2}} = \pm \, \omega \int \text{d} t$$

Now one can easily integrate indefinitely and get

$$\sin^{-1} {x\over A}=\pm \, \omega t + \theta,$$

where $\theta$ is the constant of integration.

This can be written as
$$x=A\sin (\pm \, \omega t + \theta)$$

Clearly this is nonsensical since the object can’t have two different positions at the same time. Therefore, only one of the $+$ or $-$ signs should be retained.

So my question is how to show this retention of one sign *mathematically formally* ***while*** solving the equation, without using physical or mathematical reasons ***after*** a form of solution has been arrived at?
How can one mathematically argue that since $x$ has to be a *function* of $t$, *i.e.* $x=x(t)$, after $\theta$ has been chosen? (Aren’t there differential equations whose soltuions are not functions, but curves?)

Comment: The $\pm$ can be absorbed into the $\theta$ phase. The two solutions are the same, up to a difference of $\pi$ in $\theta$. You can choose any of them, and the value of the integration constant depends on the initial condition.

Comment: @Andrei This is not what I’m asking. Assuming that it has an *initial condition* (and that too of the form corresponding to *one* (not two) position at one time instant) amounts to reasoning **after** arriving at $x=A \sin (\pm \, \omega t + \theta)$.

Comment: What I’m asking is why how we *mathematically* reason that the solution can’t have $\pm$ *after* $\theta$ has been chosen? That is why does the have to be a *function* $x=x(t)$? Can’t it be any curve (without applying physical reasons)?

Comment: The two positions are the same, just the expression is different. Say you choose the positive solution, and you get $x=A\sin(\omega t)$. I can write this as $x=A\sin(-\omega t+\pi)$. And it's the same function. You don't choose $\theta$ first. The value of that constant depends on your choice of sign

Comment: @Andrei On what reasons can you choose the $+$ or $-$ sign beforehand if you’re not given the *nature* initial condition?

Comment: Suppose you’re given an (unphysical) initial condition of *two* positions at one initial instance.

Comment: I'm not even sure how I would describe that mathematically

Comment: Due to the conservation laws.  Running the experiment backwards and for wards in time looks exactly the same (it is symetric with regards to time)  hence you can't eliminate a + or a - without reference to something outside of this equation.

Comment: @QthePlatypus Great! I was guessing that to be the case!

Comment: Maybe you could post it as an answer. After considering small subtleties when the $\pm$ sign doesn’t violate the time-reversal.

Comment: So, I conclude that some *physical* reason is necessary to get rid of $/pm$ sign.

Answer (score 1):

Initially posted as a comment, but I had more to say.

You actually can't get rid of the $\pm$ sign due to the nature of harmonic motion

- The velocity is neither strictly positive or strictly negative
- The velocity can't be uniquely determined from the position alone.

Let's say the position/velocity is given by

\begin{align} x(t) &= A\sin(\omega t + \theta) \\ \dot x(t) &= \omega A\cos(\omega t + \theta) \end{align}

within a single period $0 \le t < 2\pi/\omega$, the system always reaches the same position twice. These positions are distinguished by the sign of the velocity.

For example, at 2 different times $t_1=0$ and $t_2=(\pi-2\theta)/\omega$, we have two configurations with the same position but opposite velocities

$$ \begin{aligned} x(t_1) &= A\sin(\theta) \\ \dot x(t_1) &= \omega A\cos(\theta) \qquad \end{aligned} \begin{aligned} x(t_2) &= A\sin(\pi-\theta) = A\sin(\theta) \\ \dot x(t_2) &= \omega A\cos(\pi-\theta) = -\omega A\cos(\theta) \end{aligned} $$

So in fact, both signs are correct. This ambiguity is resolved by knowing the position and velocity at one specific time. You can't drop the $\pm$ until you arrive at the time-dependent solution.